# Entity Framework with optional child navigation property creates extra columns

Tags: entity-framework

I've just noticed a rather strange behaviour with how Entity Framework creates a Code-First DB when you have a model with a parent that has a list of children, but also an optional navigation property to one particular child: I end up with an additional nullable foreign key column on the child that I'm not expecting.  Can anyone please explain whether this column is actually necessary?  And for that matter, can anyone suggest a better way of indicating that a particular child is Selected/Active.

To elaborate:

Given this model:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Child> Children { get; set; }

    // Optional navigation property to one of the child objects.
    public int? ActiveChildId { get; set; }
    public virtual Child ActiveChild { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

I end up with the following DB:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Parents](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ActiveChildId] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Parents] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Parents]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Parents_dbo.Children_ActiveChildId] FOREIGN KEY([ActiveChildId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Children] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Parents] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Parents_dbo.Children_ActiveChildId]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Children](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ParentId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Parent_Id] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Children] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Children]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Children_dbo.Parents_Parent_Id] FOREIGN KEY([Parent_Id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Parents] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Children] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Children_dbo.Parents_Parent_Id]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Children]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Children_dbo.Parents_ParentId] FOREIGN KEY([ParentId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Parents] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Children] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Children_dbo.Parents_ParentId]
GO
```

**i.e. there is both a ParentId (NOT NULL) column on the child AND a Parent_Id (NULL) column on the child.**

It seems to me that since we've already got a 1:N foreign key relationship Parent to Child, then by adding a one-way 1:[0 or 1] Parent to Child relationship it shouldn't create another foreign key column on the child.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the `InverseProperty` attribute:

```
public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty( "Children" )]
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Or map the relationship via Fluent API and specify the FK as `ParentId`:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
            .HasMany( p => p.Children )
            .WithRequired( c => c.Parent )
            .HasForeignKey( c => c.ParentId );
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't believe either of those suggestions will help.  If I make the ParentId nullable it's no longer appropriate for my 1:N relationship, and Entity Framework already infers ParentId to be the foreign key to Parent based on the naming convention.

Comment: add `RequiredAttribute` to property if you don't want a nullable `ParentId`

Comment: added fluent api config

Comment: Ahah - brilliant!  Your example does indeed work, but it's not the **RequiredAttribute** that makes it work - it's the **InversePropertyAttribute**.  It seems that EntityFramework can't work out which relationship this is the navigation property for without this (which seems reasonable to me).  So as not to confuse anyone who reads this, can I suggest you update your answer to remove the RequiredAttribute, and then I'll mark it as the solution.  Thanks again Moho.

Comment: The answer definitely gets us the ability to read the data, but writing it results in "Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated values."

    using (var db = new Context())
    {
        var parent = new Parent();
        var child = new Child();
        parent.ActiveChild = child;
        db.Parents.Add(parent);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }