# Entity define foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-migrations

I have the following class structure, and am using Entity code first migrations to create the database from these classes:

```
public class t_ParentClass
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Unique id
    /// </summary>
    public int UNID { get; set; }
}


public class t_ChildClass
{
    /// <summary>
    /// UNID
    /// </summary>
    public int UNID { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Event Id
    /// </summary>
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Review event
    /// </summary>
    public t_ParentClass Parent { get; set; }
}
```

This setup has created a foreign key column on the table `t_ChildClass`

This is all fine and working well.

However, I am also using `Linq-to-entities` to query these tables.

The issue with the above setup is that I cannot do the following:

```
var parent = context.parent.include(x => x.child);
```

So, in order to fix this, I can change my structure to be the following:

```
public class t_ParentClass
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Unique id
    /// </summary>
    public int UNID { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Child
    /// </summary>
    public List<t_ChildClass> Child { get; set; }
}

public class t_ChildClass
{
    /// <summary>
    /// UNID
    /// </summary>
    public int UNID { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Event Id
    /// </summary>
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Review event
    /// </summary>
    public t_ParentClass Parent { get; set; }
}
```

The issue here is the migration now wants to add a new column to the child table, to represent what sees as a new foreign key to the parent table.

So, my question is:

How can I get it to recognise that the column already exists in the child table and use that to as the link between the parent and the child table, rather than making a new column.

I know I could just accept this way of doing things, but there is data is some of the tables and it is a bit of a problem to drop the foreign key and recreate.

Maybe I can do this through the `EntityTypeConfiguration` class?

Comment: Your code is correct. What is the exact error message from migration.

Comment: Parent should have a children *collection*. (Also, do yourself a favor and remove those useless `t_` prefixes).

Comment: @GertArnold He has a children collection.  If you read the whole post he explains his setup, what he did to introduce the problem, and what he's doing to fix it.  He initially didn't have the children so the child was the only one with a foreign key, he introduced the children after the DB was created and now the child is trying to make 2 foreign keys for parent (because it already had one).

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII Your right, I was sidetracked by the singular name (probably read too many posts too quickly). OP probably needs [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21716391/861716).

Comment: @GertArnold I've done the same thing too many times.  Thanks for the link also.